# Excel VBA Autofilter yesterday date by excluding weekend

Tags: excel, vba

I have a batch of data, in Column A(Date, e.g (20/7/2020)).If i want to filter this column for yesterday (exclude Sat and Sun). how can I do?

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$21")
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=2, _
        Operator:=11, Criteria2:=0
End With
```

Using the above codes, I am able to filter yesterday date which is 19/7/2020. Since yesterday is weekend, i want it to filter 17/7/2020 by excluding weekend. How do I modify the code where it will exclude weekends?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, please:

```
Sub filterYesterdayWithoutWeekends()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, strCrit As String, lastRow As Long
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
  strCrit = IIf(Not IsWeekend(Date - 1), CStr(Date - 1), _
      (IIf(Not IsWeekend(Date - 2), CStr(Date - 2), CStr(Date - 3))))
  
  With sh.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=strCrit, Operator:=xlFilterValues
  End With
End Sub
```

and the next function to determine the weekend day:

```
Private Function IsWeekend(InputDate As Date) As Boolean
    Select Case Weekday(InputDate)
        Case vbSaturday, vbSunday
            IsWeekend = True
        Case Else
            IsWeekend = False
    End Select
End Function
```